# apache commons configuration2 :ConfigurationEvent is not generated for ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder

Tags: dynamic, configuration-management, apache-commons-config

Using commons configuration2, i would like to be notified when a specific file based property changes. For that am using a ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder, PeriodicReloadingTrigger.

As per the documentation, the builder should be used as a central component and regenerate the configuration by builder.getConfiguration() when the underlying file changes. Am able to get a ConfigurationBuilderEvent.RESET notification when the file changes and using which am able to refresh my configuration with the new configuration.

However, when I try to add event listener for ConfigurationEvent.ANY, so I get notified of the actual property in the file that is changed, I do not get that notified. Any help is appreciated.

Below is my sample program to demonstrate this :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.ConfigurationBuilderEvent;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.EventListenerParameters;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.event.ConfigurationEvent;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.event.EventListener;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.reloading.PeriodicReloadingTrigger;

public class ReloadingConfigEventTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Parameters params = new Parameters();
        EventListenerParameters listenerParams = new EventListenerParameters();
        listenerParams.addEventListener(ConfigurationEvent.ANY, new EventListener<ConfigurationEvent>() {
            public void onEvent(ConfigurationEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event.getEventType().getName() +" "+event.getPropertyName());
            }
        }).addEventListener(ConfigurationBuilderEvent.RESET, new EventListener<ConfigurationBuilderEvent>() {
            public void onEvent(ConfigurationBuilderEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Event:" + event.getEventType().getName());
            }
        });

        ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration> builder = new ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration>(
                PropertiesConfiguration.class)
                        .configure(params.fileBased().setFile(new File("src/main/resource/override.conf")), listenerParams);
        PeriodicReloadingTrigger trigger = new PeriodicReloadingTrigger(builder.getReloadingController(), null, 1,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        trigger.start();

        //modify the property file during the infinite loop, the new property is picked, but the SET_PROPERTY notification is missing
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(builder.getConfiguration().getString("test.property1"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not believe this is possible, at least with the latest `commons-configuration2` library source (2.1.1). The `ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder` only populates configuration instances which derive from `FileBasedConfiguration` (for example, `PropertiesConfiguration`), and `FileBasedConfiguration` objects are all loaded by the without the use internal methods which would fire events like `ADD_PROPERTY`, `SET_PROPERTY`, etc.

I've been interested in this myself in the past, but `commons-configuration2` just isn't set up this way.